# Sorting XML file by attribute value alphabetical

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Ive got a XML File and would like to sort it like shown below by the attribute "name" in M1 alphabetical
Would be great if it could be done by linq.

Input:

```
<M1>
    <Class name="Class1">
        <M1 name="ZZAA" description="This is Last" value="0" />
        <M1 name="AABB" description="This should be first" value="3" />
        <M1 name="ACAB" description="This should be second" value="1" />
        <M1 name="ZFAA" description="This should be not here" value="32" />
    </Class>
</M1>
```

Output should look this way:

```
<M1>
    <Class name="Class1">
        <M1 name="AABB" description="This should be first" value="3" />
        <M1 name="ACAB" description="This should be second" value="1" />
        <M1 name="ZFAA" description="This should be not here" value="32" />
        <M1 name="ZZAA" description="This is Last" value="0" />
    </Class>
</M1>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does an dynamic solution exist? - So:
    <xy>
        <xx>
            <yy>
                <xy name = "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `OrderBy` and `ReplaceNodes`:

```
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("input.xml");
        doc.Root.Element("Class").ReplaceNodes(doc.Root.Element("Class").Elements("M1").OrderBy(m => (string)m.Attribute("name")));
        doc.Save("output.xml");
```

Comment: Awesome worked like a charm! - Now is my question how would it need to be modified if there is another instance between? <M1><Modul><Class>